# Need year field - not date and without thousands separator

Tags: cognito-forms

I need a Cognito Forms field that is a year. A person filling out the form enters the year when he/she joined the organization. I need to validate this field by comparing it to the person's birthdate and ensure that the person joined after age 15. I also need to use it to validate that the number of years that person has been a member of a specific chapter of this organization is not more than the total number of years that person was a member of the organization.

The year field can't be a number field because that displays the thousands separator. It can't be a text box because then it can't be used in numeric calculations.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

While we do not support just a year field. You can set up a Text field to be a year field.

Add a Text field to your form and label it 'Year'. You can then use the drop down option 'Format Validation' to accept only alphanumeric values. While this is not a true year field, it will let users enter in a year, without getting commas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I figured out how to do this. I use a textboox as you suggest. However, my problem was that I needed to use it in a numeric calculation and a textboox's value is a string. So I discovered I could use Int32() to convert it to a number. This is not well documented in your help.